# How to set up Views PHP filter?

Tags: views

I'm trying to use Views PHP filter feature to remove rows which don't contain some data (I can't just use "Hide if empty" feature, because the module returns a string even if there is no real value.

I'm using this string for a filter, however, if doesn't work - instead of filtering, view returns all values.

```
return isset($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_poloha_obce_pol[und][0][geometry]);
```

I tried to inspire myself from some of the similar issues here, but it seems to me, that everything should be correct.

I also tested this exact code as PHP field and it returns expected value.

Comment: Is the [und] and [geometry] really written exactly like that?

Comment: what is type of this field? where you put this code in php views filter (setup? value? return?)

Comment: @kari-kaariainen Yes, I copied those keys from PHP field, where it returned expected value. I determined correct values by using `print_r` function on `$data` variable.

Comment: @zhilevan The filed is of type [Postgis](http://drupal.org/project/postgis). I put that code into "Filter code" textarea. I can post screenshot if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 return empty($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_poloha_obce_pol['und'][0]);
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is probably `true` for all results, as it removes all of them.

Comment: not, if this field not empty it return false and then it will be show

Comment: Yes, I understand, that it should work **in theory**, but in reality, it does not.

Comment: try dpm(empty($data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_poloha_obce_pol['und'][0])); and wrote me what it return to you

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now,thanks for help.